# Boundary conditions for random walk

Tags: probability, random-walk

Consider a simple asymmetric random walk $S_n$ which goes up with probability $p$ and down with $1-p$.

For $b<x<a$ let 
$$r(x) = P( S_n\text{ hits }a \text{ before }b |S_0 = x).
$$ 
This probability satisfies the recurrence relation $r(x)=p \times r(x+1)+(1-p) \times r(x-1)$ which has the solution

$$
r(x)=c_1+c_2 \left(\frac{1-p}{p} \right)^x
$$
  but what are the boundary conditions? I don't quite see what these might be.

Intuitively this probability should approach $1$ if $b$ approaches $-\infty$ and $0$ if $a$ approaches $\infty$ but even if this is correct I am unable to devise an expression using this fact.

Any hint is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $S_0 = a$ then $P(S_n \text{ hits A before B}) = 1$.

On the other hand, if $S_0 = b$ then $P(S_n \text{ hits A before B}) = 0$.

These are the only boundaries. The equation is about $r(x\in [a,b])$, $a$ and $b$ are fixed.

Comment: yes but what about the condition $b<x<a$, i.e. strict inequalities?

Comment: You can define $r$ on $[a,b]$ (just look at the definition!). The equation $r(x)=p⋅r(x+1)+(1−p)⋅r(x−1) $ is only valid for $x\in (a,b)$ because of the terms $r(x\pm 1)$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcome!